# reduce memory usage in matplotlib to resolve segmentation fault

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a relatively large database using matplotlib. I've tried memory compression schemes like typecasting into `int8` or `categorical` datatype, however it returns segmentation fault irrespective of any change.

[image: dataframe.info()]

There are 7 similar dataframes I want to plot with memory usage between 961.3KB-1.3MB. This is the code snippet I'm using to plot the dataframes.

```
for col in hrlogic.columns:
    plt.subplot(5,5,i)
    plt.plot(x,hrlogic[col],label=(f"R = %d"%hrlogic[col].astype(bool).sum()))
    plt.title(col)
    plt.legend()
```

where `x` is a column pertaining to the time from another dataframe.

Comment: Segmentation faults generally happen when there's an internal error, so this one might be worth a bug report.

Comment: Can you plot each column separately, and the segfault happens if you try to plot all of them?